# How to find $(f_n)$ such that $f_n\rightarrow f$ in measure $\mu$, but the sequence $(f_n)$ is not convergent in $L_1(\mu)$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $X=\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathcal{X}=\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ with $\mu (A)=\sum_{n\in A}\frac{1}{n}$.

How to find $(f_n)$ such that $f_n\rightarrow f$ in measure $\mu$, but the sequence $(f_n)$ is not convergent in $L_1(\mu)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:** A much simpler counterexample than I initially had exists.

Consider the sequence of subsets of $\mathbb{N}$, $\left\{A_n\right\}$, given by

$$A_i = \left\{ i \right\}$$

Then in the above measure

$$\mu(A_i) = \frac{1}{i}$$

Let $f : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be the constant function that is identically zero. Let

$$f_n = nI_{A_n}$$

where $I_{A_n}$ is the indicator function for $A_n$.

Now $f_n$ clearly converges to $f$ in measure, since the measure of the set on which they differ goes to zero as $n$ goes to infinity. However $f_n$ does not converge to $f$ in the $L_1(\mu)$ norm. For a given $n \in \mathbb{N}$

$$\int_{\mathbb{N}}\left|f - f_n\right|\operatorname{d}\mu = 
\int_{\mathbb{N}}f_n \operatorname{d}\mu = n\mu(A_n) = 1$$